# Looking for a JavaScript switch control which can be used to cycle through 3 states

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Do you have suggestions for JavaScript controls or jQuery plugins that can be used to allow the user to make a boolean decision (for example: Yes/No, true/false or On/Off) but also that allows the initial state to be unknown (neither true nor false). Basically I want to be able to represent the situation where the user hasn't made a selection yet. When the user selects either of the two states he can't go back to the "unknown" state.

I found several elegant switch controls that allow the user to cycle through two states (some even look like an iPad switch button which is really nice) but I can't find any that allow a third state.

Answer (score 3):

Three states and you can’t go back to the “none” state after selecting one? Sounds like a job for… two radio buttons!

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="a"> Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="b"> Option 2</label>
```

Comment: Yes you're right but any suggestion to make it look better? Standard radio buttons are boring!

Comment: @desautelsj: Style it with CSS to look like two buttons, I suppose! Like on a blender, if that’s meaningful =) You might ask on [UX.SE] for that sort of thing.